# Q: Suspended .NET process leaks window management objects (aka. USER Objects)

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, user32

On Windows, what are all the possible creation entry points for user objects?  I have been trying to isolate a handle leak in a .NET application for quite some time now.  Here is what baffles me:

```
• Leak only occurs in window management objects (aka. USER objects - not kernel, not GDI).
• Leak only occurs when the application has focus.  Clicking on another application "pause" the leak until we click on the application window again.
• Leak occurs even if process is suspended (through task manager or debugger).
```

I've been trying to intercept any and all object creation methods, but my Visual Studio debugger remains suspiciously silent.  I do get the occasionnal call to some user32.dll methods (as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/user-objects), but nothing that would account for the leak or come close to the system limit of 10 000 objects.

Any suggestion?  Does anyone knows if some hidden system thread remains active even when my application is suspended?  Thank you.

Comment: What platform? Native Win32? Windows Forms? WPF? UWP?

Comment: .NET application with a mixture of WPF and hosted Winform controls.  But our team might just have found the cause (see answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, our team has been able to find one probable cause for the issue.  Turns out that Microsoft's documentation tells only half the story.  If at some point user and kernel objects were completely separate, recent versions of Windows have blurred the line.

As such, DDE transaction, monitor, keyboard layout, keyboard file, event hook, timer, input context, device info, touch data, gesture data and HID data should all be added to Microsoft's list of user objects.  Some kernel methods may rely on user objects to provide services to apps.

To be specific, calls to RegisterRawInputDevices will result in the application receiving WM_INPUT messages.  Those messages are backed by HID data​ and must be processed in a timely manner.  If the process is suspended, unresponsive or otherwise fails to process incoming messages, there will be an accumulation and an exhaustion of system resources.  This can quickly escalate into the problem described above and lead to an application crash.